# What is the most efficient way of caching information pulled from an API?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I am debating how I should organize my database which pulls information from Facebook's Open Graph API.  I am looking to gather information for a specific page such as:

1. Albums
2. All photos in an album
3. All comments/likes/names for all photos in an album

Is it more efficient for me to structure my database to include all this information in one table or in multiple tables (i.e. Albums table, Photos table, Comments table, etc.)?  If it matters, I will be using MySQL databases and having them accessed and read via PHP.

Comment: More efficient in terms of what? Size? Read speed? Write speed? You will need to decide what you want to optimize before a good answer about "how" can be given.

Comment: In order to accurately answer this question it is needed to know what queries you intend on making.

Comment: @George Cummins: In terms of reading speed.  I am not worried about how long it takes to write to the database nearly as much as I am worried about how long it takes to read and display information.

Comment: @erisco: In writing I will be making only Facebook api calls through the open graph and then do an SQL UPDATE of the corresponding values in the database.  As far as reading goes I will only be using SQL SELECT.  Am I still being to vague here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just absolutely no way you're going to get all this information in a single table and be able to query it effectively.  Design a relational database to store all of this information.

Answer (score 0):

What SBerg said and then, to make the reads (selects) really fast, you may also want to consider creating a dimensional model of your db (start schema or similar) for your front end UI - more info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse.

Relational db store will be great for writing and DM model for reading data. We're using this approach for our FB real estate app where we're handling millions of property records and 100s of millions of property photos.

Also, you should definitely host your MySQL db in a cloud hosted environment, no question about that!